# how to iterate through empty result set in php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am executing following query on my database through PHP,

```
SELECT count(*) as total,ifnull(status,1000) as status from xyz
WHERE user_id in( 0)  and ifnull(status,1000) in (1)
GROUP BY ifnull(status,1000)
```

After that I am iterating through that

```
foreach($result as $r)
{
    if($r->status == 1)
       // Blobk of code
}
```

but the problem is that there is no row with 1 status and that's why it's not executing the block of code.

I want that block of code to be executed.
As of now it's not getting executed as `$result` is empty.

Comment: Help you with what exactly?

Comment: can you post what you expecting as output

Comment: I think you need to use `if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){ // foreachloop}else{// any message}`

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: @dev.php I think you are not able to get what is the problem

Comment: please be more specific show your all code

Comment: Since there isn't any row which status==1 then how can you expect that it should still run...

Comment: is there any way that it should return 0 if that specific status not there??

Comment: Your query will only select the status of the first row, since doing a `COUNT()` in a query summarizes it into a single-row result. You probably want a separate count query or a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: You don't have the query you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

Hope This will help others in future,
This is what I was looking for:

```
SELECT 
            ifnull(status,1000) as status, 
            CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT no FROM detail_master b WHERE ifnull(b.status,1000) in (1) and b.id in( 0))
            THEN count(*)
            ELSE 0
            END AS total
            FROM  detail_master where ifnull(status,1000) in (1) and av_status = 1 group by ifnull(b.status,1000)
```

Output of this query is :

```
status     total
   1          0
```

Total is 0 even if no data present for id 0.